# How to use multiple database using mysqli_query?

Tags: php, mysqli, multiple-databases

How can i use multiple database (arround 30) connection using `msqli_query()`.
My query like `$query = msqli_query($conn,"select * from user where province_id = '5'")`.
So now here i want to use $conn as all database using function with switch case

In below code for all case $value are finding from an array....

```
function allDatabase($value)    {
switch ($value) {
case "1":
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "$db"); 
    return $conn;
    break;
case "2":
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "$db1");    
    return $conn;
    break;
case "3":
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "$db2");    
    return $conn;
    break;
case "4":
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "$db3");    
    return $conn; 
    break;
default:
    echo "";
 }
}
```

I can't use all database in my query....
So how can we these all connection in my query and get results from all database.
In simple words 'want to all users using all databases in one query'.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Every thing is correct except `msqli_query` typo here

Comment: But my query not fetch result from all databases. It gives all users only from current database

Comment: Where is `$db` assigned? Looks to be unset here; or outside scope.

Comment: databases $db, $db1, $db2.......and so on has static value as $db = abcd, $db1 = 12345.........

Comment: Why you need it in one query. use a foreach loop and append the data in a array using array_merge()

Comment: i need to use all return $conn in my mysqli_query. I have already found all db name in Array using another function. Then al db name in : foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
   echo  $value;
}
Now i want to use  these all $vaue sent to above function allDatabase($value) then return connection to my mysql_query(........).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
function makeConnection($dbName)    {
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "$dbName"); 
    return $conn;
}

$allResult = array();

foreach ($arr as $key=>$value) {
    $conn = makeConnection($value);
    $query = msqli_query($conn,"select * from user where province_id = '5'");
    $result = fetchDataFromSqlArray($query);
    $allResult = array_merge($allResult, $result);
}
```

Comment: @isha.. yes. this is how you can do. if user name and passwords are different for each database , you can define "$arr" as multidimensional array with db name, user name and password and then you can use them inside this for loop.

Comment: can we replace foreach loop by for loop, i want there province_id with $i not as $key. Query should be execute $i time.
I tried with for loop but it's no working correctly....

Comment: Yes you can. Type exact query here. I will be happy to help

Comment: i am using below code : `for($i=1; $i<30; $i++) { $conn = makeConnection($i); $query = msqli_query($conn,"select * from user where country_id = '$i'"); $result = msqli_fetch_array($query); $allResult = array_merge($allResult, $result); }` Where is incorrect..?? This for loop is not working in my ajax file....

Comment: ajax file ??? It's a PHP code you can't use it in ajax (that will require JavaScript)

Comment: I am finding result on my page using ajax from multiple database and it was working with `mysql`but this is not working with `mysqli`for multiple database.

Comment: Try mysqli_close($conn); after $query = msqli_query line in for loop. It May be a reason for your issue. Check and post the output

Comment: Or as I can see from your question you only need to use different databases with same user privileges. Why don't you specify database name in your query itself.  msqli_query($conn,"select * from ".$db.".user where province_id = '5'");